# How to create Single use Source with tipsi-stripe createSourceWithParams in React Native app

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I am able to create a `reusable` Source with `tipsi-stripe`'s `createSourceWithParams` method and it is processed just fine but there doesn't seem to be any option to create a `single_use` Source for the case when the user chooses not to save the card / payment method.

```
const sourceParams: ICardParams = {
        type: 'card',
        name: name,
        number: cardNumber,
        expMonth: parseInt(expiryDate.slice(0, 2), 10),
        expYear: parseInt(expiryDate.slice(3, 5), 10),
        cvc: cvc,
      };
const source: IStripeSource = await stripe.createSourceWithParams(
        sourceParams,
      );
```

Is this simply not supported in `tipsi-stripe` or am I missing something?
Also I'm using this library because the newer `stripe-react-native` library does not have any support for Sources AFAIK. I would have to upgrade my backend code as well to work with PaymentIntents instead.

Comment: `stripe-react-native` will likely never have support for Sources as it is an [older API superseded by PaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/transitioning). `tipsi-stripe` is also no longer maintained, so I'd be wary of building my Stripe integration using that! I'd recommend upgrading your integration to use both `stripe-react-native` and PaymentIntents.